# Read .csv file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I am a beginner to R, I have a file like below.

```
state            population
Alabama             4779736
Alaska               710231
Arizona             6392017   
Delaware             897934
District of Columbia 601723
```

I saved it in notepad as `"tab1.csv"`, then I use `read_csv` to read in R with

```
tab1 <- read_csv("tab1.csv")
tab1
```

and the data after read like this:

```
tab1
# A tibble: 5 x 1
 `state   \t     population`   
  <chr>                         
1 "Alabama             4779736" 
2 "Alaska     \t         710231"
3 "Arizona    \t        6392017"
4 "Delaware     \t     897934"  
5 "District of Columbia 601723"
```

My question is what `"\t"` mean and how to read this data and I hope I can get exact as input.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `read_csv("..", , sep = "\t")` and look here for more information on `\t` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter

Comment: You can use `read.table("tab1.csv", header=TRUE)` which defaults to tab as a separation marker (but needs a nudge to read the header).

Comment: your data seems like separated by tabs. as Julian answered, you should use that. for more info, on command prompt of R, type `?read_csv` to get full info (help) about  function `read_csv()`

Comment: `\t` means a "tab" character. This means it is not a CSV, where the "C" means "comma", and this data looks to be not that. This means that `read_csv` is not the right (best) function to use. You can instead use `readr::read_tsv` if you prefer to use `readr`, but all of the file-reading utilities will read it just fine, including `read.table` and `fread`.

Comment: for more - `https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table`

Comment: Another problem is with `District of Columbia`. With spaces in it this will be seen like 3 different columns. Put it between single quotes. `tab1<-read.table("tab1.csv", header = TRUE)` will work.

Comment: Thank you thank you everyone so much. I learned a lot! Such a wonderful group!

Comment: anya, I think RuiBarradas' point is salient: your tibble output suggests that there are tabs in _some_ rows but not all of them. This means that whatever created your file did so inconsistently, not adhering to any of CSV, TSV, space-delimited (with quotes), or even fixed-width formats. If it truly does not have tabs on all lines, then ... fix the process (or person) that is giving you that file. If somebody is editing it (e.g., in `Notepad.exe` or `Word.exe`), stop doing that. Parsing this file with mixed delimiters will bring a _lot_ of pain.